# I need date between minimum date and maximum date in the Sql Server in the table containing 3 rows

Tags: sql-server

I need date between minimum date and maximum date in the SQL Server in the table containing 3 rows.

```
ex:01 Jan 1992
   02 Jan 1992
   03 Jan 1992
```

i need that 02 Jan 1992

Comment: MySQL/MS SQL Server/Oracle or everything?

Comment: Please post your coding attempt and refer to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the query below is on a table with only 3 rows as your question depicts.

```
;WITH DateCTE AS
(
  SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) AS MaxDate, MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinDate
  FROM [metadata].[BuildVersion]
)
SELECT CreatedDate
FROM [metadata].[BuildVersion]
WHERE CreatedDate <> (SELECT  MaxDate FROM DateCTE)
AND CreatedDate <> ( SELECT  MinDate FROM DateCTE)
```

This should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
select date from table_name where date between '01 Jan 1992' and '03 Jan 1992';
```

You can use `between` to extract a value between any 2 values. It will be better if you give the column names and table name, so that it will be easy for other who try to answer your question.